# How to put a youtube video above an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

I have a youtube video on my page and I want it to be bordered with an image. It fits perfectly, but I can't play it.

Here is the link:

```
< iframe style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 85px;"width="431" height="270" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RHaIQWOsxaA?autoplay=0&cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And the video looks like this?

http://kepfeltoltes.hu/131024/354340238asd_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

Can somebody help me with this.

Thank you so much!

******Edit*******

Thank you, I tired the z-index, now it shows the video, but I stil can't play it. :S

******Edit*******

It's perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: You haven't provided code to replicate this?

Comment: You may want to read about CSS absolute positioning and z-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a very basic Solution

HTML:

```
<div class="video-container">
<iframe class="Video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RHaIQWOsxaA?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-container {
    background: url(http://images.amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/apple/apple-mbp2011-13-frontface_osx-lg.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 590px;
    width: 1000px;
}
.Video{
    position:absolute;
    width: 654px;
    height: 411px;
    left: 177px;
    top: 69px;
}
```

And Here's the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YHWCk/1/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a z-index of 2 to the Iframe and a z-index of 1 to the image through CSS.